# How can I store the e.target.innerText from 'button' tag when is pressed?

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, calculator

i'm in [calculator project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-calculator) and i'm in part 5. "Create the functions that populate the display when you click the number buttons. You should be storing the ‘display value’ in a variable somewhere for use in the next step." and I'm having troubles storing the value of the button pressed by the user to use later as operands and operators.
[github repository](https://github.com/yamildev/calculator)

Now, i'm trying to get and store in some var the innerText from the clicked buttons to use as  input values from the user. To do this, I chosed to use a listener inside a forEach, but at the moment only I could return the innerText to the console. Also I tried to encapsulate the following code inside a function but by scope function limitations I couldn't  return the innerText through the function.
Example of what I tried:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons-grid")
function getInner(){
buttons.forEach((button) =>{
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    return console.log(e.target.innerText)
  })
})
return e.target.innerText //doesn't work
}
```

Going on, what I need, is to think in one or two ways to store the value of the key pressed by the user, to use later as operands or operators.

Also I would like to give in knowledge that I miss some important concepts to understand what i'm doing and what I have to do, so for that, I will give thanks for any kind of illustration about it as learning resources too.

What i'm doing:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons-grid")

buttons.forEach((button) =>{
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    return console.log(e.target.innerText)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable outside of the event listener function and assign it the value of e.target.innerText when a button is clicked:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons-grid");
let displayValue = '';

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    displayValue = e.target.innerText;
    console.log(displayValue);
    // do something with the displayValue variable
  })
```

});